# Why does python can't import pathlib when i run it from linux terminal instead of an IDE(Thonny)

Tags: python, linux, utf-8

The only special circumstances are that:
it runs on a raspberry pi
its executed on linux
the file contains special letters like äöü(yes i did

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

in every file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `#!/usr/bin/python` I think the IDE knows the paths and corrects them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux distros include both Python 2 and Python 3, with the default `python` executable being Python 2 rather than Python 3.

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) was added to the standard library in Python 3.4, so importing it will fail if the import is done in the Python 2 interpreter.

Adding the shebang line

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

or specifying the Python 3 executable when calling your program

```
$ python3 myprog.py
```

should ensure that th program is executed by Python 3, and `pathlib` is importable..